# Edit Top 200 Row ... of a Type - Sql Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to use the same editor which I have for "Edit Top 200 rows" but for a certain kind of statement.

Is it possible to change this "Edit Top N rows where [CONDITION]". I don´t mean that this is showed in the centext menu. I´m just looking for the same kind of editor which is shown when "Edit top 200 rows" is used.

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio v17.9

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Just select the normal "Edit top XXX rows" and when it is opened, click the "Show SQL Pane" button from the toolbar (or press Ctrl+3):

[image]

You will see the select top from your table statement. Just write the where clause you want and click "Execute SQL" (Ctrl+R):

[image]

Comment: Thx a lot works